# Can I install express without Internet access?

Tags: node.js, module

I have node.js installed in my work machine and I want to experiment with express, but seems like internet access is blocked from the console (I'm using windows BTW).

Is there a way to download the express package and use a command for npm to install it from a local folder instead of internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [docs](http://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) says, you can. You need `npm install <tarball file>`:

> Install a package that is sitting on the filesystem. Note: if you just want to link a dev directory into your npm root, you can do this more easily by using `npm link`.
>
> Example:
>
> `npm install ./package.tgz`

Comment: Thanks, I did tried that before posting the question but the missing `./` made it look in internet anyways.